# Orange Nura phone not recognized on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mtp

When I plug my orange phone on my ubuntu 14.04 computer, I see the following logs :

```
Jul 11 11:30:00 philippe-Dell-DM061 kernel: [588445.733075] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 4
Jul 11 11:30:13 philippe-Dell-DM061 kernel: [588458.592068] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Jul 11 11:30:13 philippe-Dell-DM061 kernel: [588458.724967] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1bbb, idProduct=af00
Jul 11 11:30:13 philippe-Dell-DM061 kernel: [588458.724976] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul 11 11:30:13 philippe-Dell-DM061 kernel: [588458.724981] usb 1-3: Product: Android
Jul 11 11:30:13 philippe-Dell-DM061 kernel: [588458.724986] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Android
Jul 11 11:30:13 philippe-Dell-DM061 kernel: [588458.724990] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: b05c6268
Jul 11 11:30:13 philippe-Dell-DM061 kernel: [588458.726395] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jul 11 11:30:13 philippe-Dell-DM061 kernel: [588458.726487] scsi8 : usb-storage 1-3:1.0
Jul 11 11:30:13 philippe-Dell-DM061 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-3"
Jul 11 11:30:13 philippe-Dell-DM061 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
```

There is an automatic volume mount on USB Driver with various drivers but I can't find the linux one.

Has somone already had this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay at the begining it was not an ubuntu issue but it became one : 
First You have to enable MTP in the storage setting **when the phone is connected** with USB cable :

Storage > Options > USB connexion

But ubuntu still can't recognize the phone as a MTP device.

I edited the /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules and saw that there was not the idVendor 1bbb with product af00. So I added the line :

```
# Nura phone
ATTR{idVendor}=="1bbb", ATTR{idProduct}=="af00", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

Then ubuntu sees the phone. Note that there is still the automatic mount of a USB driver directory but when you close it, the android phone is mounted normally.